# GTK3 FileChooser: Save dialog has no Recent item

Tags: gtk3

Ubuntu Studio 19.10
GTK 3.24.12

GTK3 FileChooser Save dialog has no Recent places Item.

How can I add it to the left sidebar?

Comment: Did you tried to press `<Alt>+<R>` in the dialog?

Comment: @N0rbert thanks, I forgot that! Quite discoverable feature, I would say. You should elaborate your comment in an answer.

Comment: yeah, I know about this feature. but this is a redundant action. it's not handy if I use mouse to manipulate and my other hand is busy (or absent in case of disabled people). it is not very friendly method imho. but it is workaround of course.

Answer (score 3):

For dialogs without *Recent* button you can always press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a workaround.